# Subplots in forloop do not appear in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

In the following code as it is obvious we have subplot. the first for loop makes 8 plots or 4 plots with 2 subplots `(4 *2 = 8`). But  the problem is in this code the first plot is shown and other ones do not appear. What should I do to see all plots of`for x in range(len(ng))`.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
for x in range(len(ng)):
    for xx in range(1,819):
            Ju_list=[]
            ET_list=[]
            ET1_list=[]
            Unu_list=[]
            z_list=[]
            uf_list=[]
            for z in np.arange(1,7):
                    Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                    Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                    lim = Ju - Jl
                    if lim > 1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if Ju<7:
                            Ju_list.append(dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1])
                            ET_list.append(ET(xx, z, ng[x], 1e-24, Tg[x], 1)/(2.73*(1+z)))
                            ET1_list.append(ET(xx, z, ng[x], 1e-20,Tg[x], 1)/(2.73*(1+z)))))
                            z_list.append(z)

                            ax1.plot(z_list, ET_list)#,label="test1")
                            ax1.title.set_text(f'Fig1:Tg={Tg[x]}')
                            ax2.plot(z_list, ET1_list)
                            ax2.title.set_text(f'Fig1:Tg={Tg[x]}')

                            #ax1.plot(Ju_list, Unu_list)

                        else:
                            pass


    plt.show()
```

Comment: Move the plt.show() outside both the for loops

Comment: @Sheldore No! We should have 8 plot in this way we have all plots in one. we should have in side the first for loop to have all possible plots of iterate `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating only one figure at the beginning using `fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)`. I think what you want to do is to create `len(ng)` figures:

```
for x in range(len(ng)):
    fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
    for xx in range(1,819):
            Ju_list=[]
            ET_list=[]
            ET1_list=[]
            Unu_list=[]
            z_list=[]
            uf_list=[]
            for z in np.arange(1,7):
                    Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                    Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                    lim = Ju - Jl
                    if lim > 1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if Ju<7:
                            Ju_list.append(dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1])
                            ET_list.append(ET(xx, z, ng[x], 1e-24, Tg[x], 1)/(2.73*(1+z)))
                            ET1_list.append(ET(xx, z, ng[x], 1e-20,Tg[x], 1)/(2.73*(1+z)))))
                            z_list.append(z)

                            ax1.plot(z_list, ET_list)#,label="test1")
                            ax1.title.set_text(f'Fig1:Tg={Tg[x]}')
                            ax2.plot(z_list, ET1_list)
                            ax2.title.set_text(f'Fig1:Tg={Tg[x]}')

                            #ax1.plot(Ju_list, Unu_list)

                        else:
                            pass


    plt.show()
```

Comment: Of course I think I have seen you in Scuola Normale Superior di Pisa. Maybe

Comment: It might be, but I've been there only a couple of times